# Progress bar not working?

Tags: python, progress-bar

```
import time

for i in range(100):
  print('*',end='')
  time.sleep(0.1)
```

why this code is not working for showing progress?
Expected output was to be showing a progress '****************'.

Comment: What is it doing for you? It works for me. https://repl.it/repls/TreasuredPerfumedIndianpangolin

Comment: @user2896976 it wait for some time and then print '*' 100 times, it does not print like a progress bar should do.

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: i wrote script and running it from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Stdout is buffered. You can flush it with a call to `sys.stdout.flush()` after each `print`. Or you can add `flush=True` to your print command instead of doing an explicit flush:

```
print('*', end='', flush=True)
```

Comment: Can u please tell me what is flush and why it is used and how sys.stdout.flush? I mean can you what the hack is going in this code internally??

Comment: @user8751232, stdout is where `print` output goes by default. In order to improve performance, stdout is normally buffered. Typically, stdout is line buffered. That is, nothing is actually printed until an entire line is ready to print. Flush means to push everything that is accumulated out of the buffer, so `sys.stdout.flush()` pushes everything out of the buffer and onto your screen. The `flush=True` does the same thing. You can also eliminate buffering for an entire application, but you would not want to do that under normal circumstances.